# memory leak in php with recursion

Tags: php, memory, recursion, memory-leaks

```
function createUniqueName($name, $i = 0)
{
    $names = array('backup');

    if($i != 0) {
        $newname = $name.'-'.$i;
    } else {
        $newname = $name;
    }

    if(in_array($newname, $names)) {
        $newname = createUniqueName($name, $i++);
    }

    return $newname;
}

echo createUniqueName('backup', 0);
```

Unfortunately this causes a memory leak and I don't know why. Its a normal recursion. Any ideas?

Error received is:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /Users/Tim/Sites/tests/uniquename.php on line 16
```

Comment: This isn't a memory leak - It is properly termed as infinite recursion, in which your function recurses until there is insufficient resources to continue recursing, so it is kicked.

Answer (score 2):

This code results in the function being run indefinitely, also it doesn't do what you think it does because $names is a local variable so within that scope it always contains one instance of backup. When you do $i++ that post increments, you should do ++$i  so the value actually changes before it goes into the function call., otherwise you're always passing 0 into the function.

```
createUniqueName($name, $i++);
```

Means "After I run createUniqueName($name, $i) increment $i."

If you change it to

```
 createUniqueName($name, ++$i);
```

You will get closer to the intended behavior (the recursion will not be infinite).

I'm going to leave the variable scope issue up to you as an exercise in figuring out where that goes.

Comment: thanks that helped. the scope issue is not really apparent, since it only was for testing purposes. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$newname = createUniqueName($name, $i++);
```

`$i++` is post-increment, i.e. it will increment the variable after the recursive call is made.

Therefore the recursion is infinite because it will always call the function with the same arguments.